# How to tell if $\sqrt{e^x}$ is an integer?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Is there a fast way to determinate if $\sqrt{e^x}$ is an integer if the only thing you know is that $e^x$ is an integer

I use $e$ as mathematical constant $e$, but you can change it if it helps to solve the problem.

At this moment I just comput $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ and check if it's an integer.

Comment: There's a square root algorithm. I doubt that there's anything special about the form $e^x$. (BTW, I deleted my answer after the question was clarified.)

Comment: @CarlHeckman Yeah I saw, sorry.

Comment: This may depend on how large the numbers are. In computer arithmetic your test is quite dangerous unless your definition of "integer" is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Sorry comment was truncated. In general, if you already have an integer, the fastest way is probably to extract the square root. Before that, usually, you can use some modular considerations to exclude some numbers. For example, if your number $n$ is a square, then $n$ mod 48 can only be one of the numbers $\{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 33, 36\}$. Tests like that. If your numbers are large, you can check how the C library GMP performs this test (function mpz_perfect_square_p) for inspiration.